# rigid motion of cube

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How do we know without looking at cube that $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)(5\ 6\ 7\ 8)$ is representative rigid motion of a cube but $(1\ 8\ 3\ 6)(2\ 5\ 4\ 7)$ is not, where the cube is as given below?[image]

I.e., how to know which element of $S_8$ is rigid motion of cube and which not?

Comment: Without looking at the cube? Without looking at the cube, how do you even know what the numbers 1, 2, ..., mean?

Comment: I think without looking here means without trying to imagine the permutation.

Comment: The second prmutation for example reverse the order of the face ${1,2,3,4}$, so it can't represent a rigid motion.